# ScatterViewItem Custom Shape

Tags: wpf, pixelsense, scatterview

I have a ScatterViewItem which contains a Canvas

```
                <Ellipse x:Name="Outer_Ellipse" Fill="White" Width="200" Height="200"></Ellipse>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Canvas.Top ="15" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Right="15" Canvas.Bottom="15" Width="170" Height="170" ></Ellipse>

            </Canvas>
        </s:ScatterViewItem>
```

Id like to provide a Custom Shape so that the default rectangle shape is not show (here is a picture of my current implementation [image].

I followed this example here [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804843(Surface.10).aspx) and have consulted the Puzzle that comes with the SDK but I am unable to get it working, my ScatterViewItem is blank.

I defined a path in the SurfaceWindow.Resources

```
 <Path x:Key="ScatterShape" Fill="Blue">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry 
                RadiusX="200"
                RadiusY="200">
            </EllipseGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

And copied the style attributes from the link above. I created my CustomShape.cs as instructed and then created the ScatterViewItem.

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path path;
path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)Resources["ScatterShape"];
CustomShape poly = new CustomShape(path.Data);
ScatterViewItem item = new ScatterViewItem();
item.Content = poly;
item.CanScale = false;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = poly;
item.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.DataContextProperty, binding);
scatter.Items.Add(item)
```

Im slightly confused with the above code since my understanding with the line

```
item.Content = poly
```

would overwrite the content of the ScatterViewItem (i.e in my case the Canvas or in another case say an Image).  For the time being I don't need to move or scale the ScatterView item so no shadows are neccessary I just simply want to remove the rectangular box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying the [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) for the ScatterViewItem.

If you want to remove all the visual features of the scatterview then I guess you could get away with an empty template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type s:ScatterViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template"> 
        <Setter.Value> 
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:ScatterViewItem}"> 
            <ContentPresenter /> 
          </ControlTemplate> 
        </Setter.Value> 
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The above template will change all scatterview items to have a blank template, but you could give it a `x:Key="YourStyleName"` and set the [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) of the ScatterView in question to only affect that scatter view.

Please note that if you use Expression Blend, you may need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll` to do this or Blend may crash when editing the template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciated. I'd spent hours trying to follow the jigsaw example in the SDKand got no where. I hadn't realised how simple it was to do using the ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the shadow, so that the ScatterViewItem is no longer visible.

Assuming that item is your ScatterViewItem:

```
item.ApplyTemplate();
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
item.ShowsActivationEffects = false;
Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome ssc;
ssc = item.Template.FindName("shadow", item) as Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome;
ssc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar Problem.
Here is my code.

```
 <s:ScatterView>
    <s:ScatterView.Items>
        <s:ScatterViewItem Height="1721" Width="2169">                
            <Canvas >
                <Path Data="M0 2728 l0 -1012 28 26 c23 21 32 24 61 17 31 -6 40 -3 75 27 38 32 99 114 92 122 -6 5 -46 -21 -46 -30 0 -15 -56 -58 -75 -58 -29 0 -105 74 -105 102 0 12 14 37 32 55 31 32 32 34 20 78 -20 74 -17 82 29 89 22 4 44 4 49 1 13 -8 23 54 11 69 -8 10 -6 17 8 30 12 11 16 25 13 41 -4 24 -3 25 24 15 25 -10 31 -9 43 9 7 12 24 21 37 21 25 0 30 10 14 26 -5 5 -7 20 -3 32 7 29 34 25 48 -6 12 -27 20 -28 38 -1 13 18 24 20 74 18 32 -2 173 -2 314 -1 l256 2 12 113 c6 61 12 191 12 287 1 96 5 182 10 191 14 27 76 61 98 54 24 -7 29 -20 37 -103 10 -106 29 -115 65 -33 24 57 70 104 95 99 10 -1 29 -25 43 -53 37 -72 66 -79 141 -38 78 44 123 50 180 25 88 -38 122 -38 197 0 64 31 75 33 193 36 77 3 145 -1 177 -9 45 -10 61 -10 115 5 135 37 121 41 253 -81 64 -59 124 -111 133 -114 27 -10 473 0 515 12 47 12 84 47 92 86 22 99 71 155 143 159 27 2 79 17 118 34 46 21 97 35 153 41 64 7 100 18 150 44 36 19 86 37 111 41 25 4 65 17 90 29 52 26 113 39 140 30 29 -9 25 -49 -10 -89 -25 -28 -29 -38 -21 -59 5 -14 15 -28 21 -32 12 -8 3 -73 -13 -94 -16 -19 17 -43 103 -76 66 -25 80 -27 188 -23 109 4 121 6 176 36 32 18 67 32 77 32 25 0 24 12 -1 35 -13 12 -20 29 -18 44 2 21 10 27 38 32 39 6 102 40 140 75 23 21 30 22 64 13 52 -14 82 -5 94 30 8 22 18 30 45 35 37 7 73 38 63 55 -9 14 -94 40 -158 47 l-58 7 0 87 c0 48 -3 90 -7 93 -3 4 -5 35 -4 70 3 73 24 102 105 142 l50 25 -2592 0 -2592 0 0 -1012z" Stroke="Black"></Path>
....
....
  </Canvas>
        </s:ScatterViewItem>
    </s:ScatterView.Items>
</s:ScatterView>
```

There are so many shapes in the canvas and the size of the canvas is also much higher.
so when i run the application, The canvas doesn't get re size when i re size the ScatterViewItem. And Event the Canvas i shown outside of the ScatterViewItem.